# Images that cannot be staged or discarded in my git project

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

In my git project i have some images that i'm unable to **stage** or **discard**. When i view it source tree and discard it **before image** and `after image` of it keeps swapping.

I tried `git add .` also but it didn't work. I really want to get rid of them from showing as modified. How can i achieve it?

(I don't want to remove the image, i just want to remove it from showing modified.) In source tree it's always in the unstaged file list

Comment: Can you provide the output of `git status`?  Try `git add -A` to add everything.

Comment: Tried git add -A still it was there. What i did was removed and it split into 2 different files. Then discarded one and pushed the other